# How to parse Json response inside square brackets?

Tags: javascript

I get the following `Json` response:

```
"kind": "analytics#gaData",
"id": "c",
"rows": [
    [
      "/de/cart.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/de/cart_details.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/de/cart_login.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/de/order_summary.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/fr/cart.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/fr/cart_details.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/fr/cart_login.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/fr/order_summary.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/it/cart.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/it/cart_details.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/it/cart_login.aspx",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "/it/order_summary.aspx",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
```

In `Javascript`, how can I possibly loop through this array (?) in order to retrieve its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you'd traverse any other array. Simply, instead of having their properties stored under property names in a map, the objects that make up this array have their properties stored under given indexes in an array.

```
theJsonObject.rows.forEach( function(row) {
    var url = row[0];
    var n = row[1];
    do stuff with url and n...
});
```

`forEach` could be replaced by anything appropriate for the particular circumstances. For instance, if you'd like to transform it into an array of regular objects with named properties :

```
var withNamedProperties = theJsonObject.rows.map( function(row) {
    return {
        url:row[0],
        n:row[1]
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, just one question, with your first method i get the error: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined(…) , my Json contains also 2 more keys, not only "rows", is it related to this? (i've edited the json in my answer)

Comment: This means that the variable that I've named `theJsonObject` does not hold the value that you're showing us, nor any value at all. It's `undefined`, and therefore can not hold a `rows` property. In the best case you may have misspelled it somewhere in your code. In the worst case there's something wrong with the upstream data flow. Since you seem to be an Android/iOS guy, JS can feel frustrating to somebody used to static languages, since a misspelling can go unnoticed before runtime. You'll feel better off running a linter like jshint all the time. :)

Comment: Yeah it is! :D thanks for your suggestions :) Btw it's not a typo, I think there's a problem with my Json structure but i'll fix it somehow, thanks again :)